# Div scroll down and scroll up with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am noob in jquery. I am trying to get this animation:
when the mouse over or click each menu collapse separately and when i click another time, the menu scroll up again. I have write this code but i don't know why it don't work ! Please help. 
Thanks

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

          $(".lead-title-index").on('click',function() {
              
              if(clicked)
              {
              clicked=false;
                  &(".featured-content").slideDown("slow");
                  
              }
              else
              {
              clicked=true;
              &(".featured-content").slideUp("slow");
              }


              });

        });
```

```css
.featured-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
  background: #2E2E2E;
}
.lead-title-index {
  background: #FFBF00;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the `&` in `&(".featured-content")` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes here.

**First**:

Change

```
&(".featured-content").slideDown("slow");
&(".featured-content").slideUp("slow");
```

to

```
$(".featured-content").slideDown("slow");
$(".featured-content").slideUp("slow");
```

As `&` is not a valid jquery syntax.

**Second**:

the variable `clicked` is not defined. You should define it globally after `document.ready` function.

Your final code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked;
    $(".lead-title-index").on('click', function () {
        if (clicked) {
            clicked = false;
            $(".featured-content").slideDown("slow");   
        } else {
            clicked = true;
            $(".featured-content").slideUp("slow");
        }
     });
});
```

You can check out the working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/akashrajbanshi/6ggvfeho/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

          $(".lead-title-index").on('click',function() {
              
              $(".featured-content").slideToggle("slow");

              });

        });
```

```css
.featured-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
  background: #2E2E2E;
}
.lead-title-index {
  background: #FFBF00;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need the `clicked` flag. Change `&` to `$` (I am sure it's a mistake). All you need is as simple as the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lead-title-index").on('click',function() {

        var $featuredContent = $(".featured-content");
        $featuredContent.is(":hidden") && $featuredContent.slideDown("slow") || $featuredContent.slideUp("slow");
    });    
});
```

```css
.featured-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
  background: #2E2E2E;
}
.lead-title-index {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFBF00;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Even better, try [jQuery.slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) which is a short hand for slideUp and slideDown based on the display state of the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lead-title-index").on('click',function() {
        $(".featured-content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all of you folk, but what i need is that:
in first time, when mouse hover `.lead-title-index` , the `.featured-content` will appear.
In second time, when the user click  `.lead-title-index` , the `.featured-content` will disappear.